# Bubblesort algorithm producing enexpected results

Tags: python, python-3.x

Forgive me if I do not understand the topic well.
I am implementing a basic(found it on youtube) bubble sort algorithm. As opposed to the example "list = [3, 4, 5, 9, 0, 2, 1]" I decided to try and implement different numbers and got an organized but not "sorted" list, from the perspective I learned. I am not unhappy with the output I am just curious what others have to say about my varying results and possibly get some insight on this.

This is using python on Visual-studio with a windows computer.

The original code is:

```
  def bubblesort(list):
      print("bubblesort")

      for k in range(0,len(list)-1, 1):
          for i in range(0,len(list)-1,1):
              if list [i] > list[i + 1]:
                  temp = list[i]
                  list[i] = list[i + 1]
                  list[i + 1] = temp
  list = [43, 7, 30, 234, 35, 77, 79, 45, 34, 21, 26]
  print(list)
  bubblesort(list)
  print(list)

  outputs:
  [43, 7, 30, 234, 35, 77, 79, 45, 34, 21, 26]
  bubblesort
  [7, 21, 26, 30, 34, 35, 43, 45, 77, 79, 234]
```

This is how I altered to explore results:

```
 def bubblesort():
    for i in range(0, len(list)-1, 1):
            if list[i] > list[i + 1]:
                list[i] = list[i + 1]



list = [10,110,13,00,0,110]
list = [10,00,11,00,0,1111]
list = [10,101,00,10,0,110]

print(list)
print(list)
print(list)
```

sorry about the randomness of my numbers, I messed with a few to see if it would sort the same(and it did, exactly the same). It lined certain numbers up in columns, which is cool, but I expected them to be sorted in order of value like above or even include different numbers I added after.
So basically I expected something along the lines of this:

```
[0,00,10,13,110,110]
[0,00,00,10,11,1111]
[0,00,10,10,101,110]
```

The actual output is:

```
[10, 101, 0, 10, 0, 110]
[10, 101, 0, 10, 0, 110]
[10, 101, 0, 10, 0, 110]
```

Comment: Your altered code is not clear. Is it your full code? If it is, then the actual output should be different based on the code you provided.

Comment: Please edit the final implementation to a code snippet that a user can run and duplicate the issue. There are missing function calls.

Also, your implementation seems is incorrect. You have gotten rid of the entire inner loop of swapping through. Also, the value for `list[i]` is lost when you replace it with `list[i+1]`

Answer (score 1):

By doing

```
list = [10,110,13,00,0,110]
list = [10,00,11,00,0,1111]
list = [10,101,00,10,0,110]
```

you assign new content to `list` in each line, so this code is in fact equivalent to

```
list = [10,101,00,10,0,110]
```

I would alter code into following form:

```
def bubblesort(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        if lst[i] > lst[i + 1]:
            lst[i] = lst[i + 1]

lst1 = [10,110,13,00,0,110]
lst2 = [10,00,11,00,0,1111]
lst3 = [10,101,00,10,0,110]

bubblesort(lst1)
bubblesort(lst2)
bubblesort(lst3)

print(lst1) #output: [10, 13, 0, 0, 0, 110]
print(lst2) #output: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1111]
print(lst3) #output: [10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 110]
```

Note that I added `lst` argument for `bubblesort` so it could be used not only on one variable with fixed name. Please avoid using `list` as variable name in Python language, as there exist already built-in `list` function.

Note that that `bubblesort` function is not proper implementation of sorting, although as I am confused what do you want exactly to do, I left it as is.

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot. There really wasn't a goal I was just curious why it sorted in a way I didn't expect. Your insight is appreciated